# How do I manage Event to Command in Xamarin.Forms and MvxListView

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm new to MvvmCross and I'm trying to bind my ItemTapped to an MvxCommand. I'm using MvvmCross 6.0.1, Xamarin.Forms and MvxListView component.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MvxListView.ItemClicked might do the job.
See for example the [star wars API Mvvmcross sample](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/blob/master/StarWarsSample/StarWarsSample.Forms/StarWarsSample.Forms/Views/PeoplePage.xaml).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use Reusable `EventToCommandBehavior` made by Xamarin team. More info about it you can find on official Xamarin docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior).

Also there is a GitHub repository with source code and sample of using it [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior).

No matter if you are using `MvxCommand` it should work because even `MvxCommand` at some point is inheriting from `ICommand`

Wish you good luck with coding!

Comment: No! Not Yet. I was worried about MvvmCross implementation if they have something flexible, I mean, I'm using MvxListView so they should provide something ready to go! lolo